# Select2 plugin: Showing selected options outside the form element

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I'm working on a multi-select dropdown using the Select2 plug-in. However, I have some styling issues that I can't seem to figure out.

The Select2 plugin allows you to select multiple options from a dropdown menu, showing the selected options nicely inside the dropdown bar.

What I'm trying to do is instead of showing it inside the dropdown bar, I want to show the selected options outside, stacked on each other (i.e. one on each row).

Here is a codepen with my current progress:

I believe I have to play around with this selector

```
.select2-container{
   *:focus{
     outline:0px;
   }
}
```

but aside from that, I can't quite get my head around it.

My styling currently produces this:

[image]

and I wish to produce this (with full width, i.e. table format):

[image]

I'd be much appreciated if someone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css clear property to do that. Add this to your css file.

```
.select2-container--bgform .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This has made it such that the options are all in their own row, but the options are still not placed under the form element. See https://gyazo.com/f56a7823d1e820f2a873faf9f82bd75f